# Wifi stops working during upgrade attempt Ubutu 20.04

Tags: networking, upgrade, lubuntu

I have a Dell D630 that had been working on Lubuntu.  I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 and got the Wifi card working with information I found on the web.  This was several months ago.

Last week AT&T upgraded my DSL to Fiber, I put in the new router password, everything worked fine.

Yesterday I got a message about an update, so I allowed it.  Part way through the download quit and my wifi card stopped working.

I tried reusing the fix I had before, didn't work.  After looking at other options, I reinstalled Ubuntu 20.04 from scratch.  When the message showed up for the update, I said "Do not update".

Finally today I booted the D630 and the Wifi came up!

Any thoughts?

Comment: "*Part way through the download quit and my wifi card stopped working*" is a clear sign that the upgrade was NOT the cause. Ubuntu finishes downloading the entire upgrade before installing the first package. Had an upgrade been the cause, your download would have been completed first.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me, with a Dell laptop. It's an updated kernel (~5.8.0.36) issue. try listing your network devices first:

> sudo lshw -c network

If your wireless interface appears 'unclaimed', this is what fixed things:

> sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source
> sudo apt-get install broadcom-sta-source
> sudo apt-get install broadcom-sta-dkms
> sudo apt-get install broadcom-sta-common

more on this link:  [Ubuntu bcmwl package](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/+bug/1878045)

Good luck :)